# Missing artifact oracle:sdoapi:jar: 11.2.0

Tags: java, eclipse, oracle, maven, eclipse-plugin

I have a maven project with these dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>sdoapi</artifactId>
    <version>11.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

and I have this error on the pom.xml file, and I have already cleaned my repository :

```
Missing artifact oracle:sdoapi:jar:
 11.2.0
```

But the file is clearly in the maven repository

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/oracle/sdoapi/11.2.0

Doing `mvn clean install`

I got this error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project geohotels: Could not resolve dependencies for project geohotels:geohotels:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find oracle:sdoapi:jar:11.2.0 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
```

But before the error I see this after cleaning everything:

```
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/oracle/sdoapi/11.2.0/sdoapi-11.2.0.pom
[WARNING] The POM for oracle:sdoapi:jar:11.2.0 is missing, no dependency information available
```

Comment: what happens when you do mvn clean install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed it manually and it works:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=sdoapi-11.2.0.jar -DgroupId=oracle -DartifactId=sdoapi  -Dversion=11.2.0  -Dpackaging=jar
```

Comment: Years old, but in case someone else stumbles across this, it was likely because the dependency was not located in the standard maven central repo-- it was instead located at either Datanucleas or the Querydsl repositories.  In sbt for example you have to add like:   resolvers += "Datanucleus" at "http://www.datanucleus.org/downloads/maven2/"